# Value not getting stored in rails instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple form which records Payments received :

```
<label>Client Name*</label>
<%= f.collection_select :client_id, Client.all, :id, :name, {prompt:"Select Client"},{ class: "form-control"} %>
<label>Service Name</label>
<%= f.collection_select :service_id, Service.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Select Service"},{ class: "form-control"}%><label>Payment Amount</label>
<%= f.text_field :amount, placeholder: "Enter the amount received",class: "form-control" %> 
<label>Payment Date</label> <br/>
<%= f.date_select :recieved_date, placeholder: "Enter the payment  date",class: "form-control" %><br/>
<br/>
<%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

The values are then passed on the controller:

```
def create
@payment = Payment.new(payment_params)
order = Order.where("client_id = ? and service_id = ?", payment_params[:client_id], payment_params[:service_id]).pluck(:id)
@payment.order_id = order[0]
if @payment.save
  redirect_to new_payment_path, notice: "Successfully created Payment!"
else
  render action: 'new'
end
end
```

As you can observe, the line
    order = Order.where("client_id = ? and service_id = ?",   payment_params[:client_id], payment_params[:service_id]).pluck(:id) attempts to store the order_id based on the  client_id and service_id. However this is not working and the order object is getting saved with a nil value when being saved (when the validation to check for order_id is removed that is)

Why is this ? any hints please

Comment: What's in `payment_params`? Try printing it out with `p payment_params`. It would probably output to the logs.

Comment: payment_params doesn't have this order_id field which i am attempting to save into the object. I am trying to calculate this value from the controller and then create the new object

Comment: When you say "the order object is getting saved with a nil value" do you mean the `@payment` object? Because that's the only object you're saving. Again, what's in `payment_params`?

Comment: the issue was resolved after a server restart in nitrous..not sure how it happened :p thanks for your help